# Ajax passing null data to razor page handler

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

so I have this ajax POST which passes an object with a list of objects(RaffleTicketNumberModel) as a property as the following:

```
// id comes as parameter to this function
const TicketNumbers = localStorage.getItem(id);
    const numbers = JSON.parse(TicketNumbers);

const dataToSend = {
    RaffleTicketId: null,
    RaffleScheduleId: scheduleId,
    UserId: user,
    DatePaid: new Date().toISOString(),
    Status: true,
    Active: true,
    AmountPaid: amountPaid,
    UserModel: null,
    RaffleScheduleModel: null,
    RaffleTicketNumberModel: numbers
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'RaffleSellsPage?handler=CreateRaffleTicket',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('XSRF-TOKEN',
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend)
}).then(function () {
    // ...
});
```

It hits the hanlder successfully but the problem is that the parameter that gets it in the razor page handler (dataToSend) always comes null. This is my page class and handler:

```
using ApiAccess;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tiempos_FE.Pages.Vendor.Sells
{
    public class RaffleSellsPageModel : PageModel
    {

        [BindProperty]
        public ApiAccess.RaffleTicketModel RaffleTicket { get; set; }
        readonly RaffleTicketClient raffleTicketClient = new(new HttpClient());

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }

        public JsonResult OnPostCreateRaffleTicket(RaffleTicketModel dataToSend)
        {
            var result = dataToSend;
            return new JsonResult(result);
        }

    }
}
```

I've tried several solutions online but none of them seems to work for me, like attatching the data to the request body and using `[FromBody] RaffleTicketModel dataToSend` to retrieve it and also passing and recieveing the object as a complete string, by replacing the Ajax contentType with `contentType: 'text/plain'`, but still comes null

As you can see in the following image, ASP.Net Core does not bound the model with the parameter object(as long as I know ASP.Net Core does this):

[image: Debugger when hits]

This is my request payload:

[image: Request Payload]

Am I doing something wrong or missing something? Thanks a lot for the help.

**Notes:**

- Note the I am passing the object with the navigation properties as null (using Entity Framework) does this affect it at all?

Also there is a small typo in RaffleTicketnumbers's property amoutPaid but the Model has the same typo so it should work as well. I will include the model

Just for reference:

```
public class RaffleTicketModel
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RaffleTicketId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RaffleSchedule")]
    public int RaffleScheduleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserModel")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DatePaid { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double AmountPaid { get; set; }

    public UserModel UserModel { get; set; }

    public RaffleScheduleModel RaffleScheduleModel { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RaffleTicketNumberModel> RaffleTicketNumberModel { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: what does your page class (as well as page handler) look like? this is important because it is related to how you setup the model binding.

Comment: because you send json via the request body, you need to use `FromBodyAttribute` to decorate the handler's parameter like this `[FromBody] RaffleTicketModel dataToSend`

Comment: I tried this again, didn't hit the handler, I changed Ajax property `data` for `body` and it hit the handler but the parameter is still null

Comment: when it does not hit the handler, can you take a look in the window ***Output*** to see if there is any error printed there?

Comment: can you try without setting `contentType: 'application/json',`, write all your properties in `const dataToSend = {}` in small letters and set your INT properties to 0 (not NULL, because you have them defined as `INT`, not nullable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RaffleTicketId` is int type,but you use `RaffleTicketId: null,`you need to set it to int type,for example,`RaffleTicketId: 0,`and you need to use`[FromBody]` in handler.Here is a working demo:

View:

```
<button onclick="PostData()">click</button>
```

js:

```
function PostData() {
        var numbers = [];
        numbers[0] = { raffleNumber: 5, amountPaid: 2000 };
        numbers[1] = { raffleNumber: 4, amountPaid: 2000 };
        numbers[2] = { raffleNumber: 3, amountPaid: 2000 };

        const dataToSend = {
            RaffleTicketId: 0,
            RaffleScheduleId: 0,
            UserId: "",
            DatePaid: new Date().toISOString(),
            Status: true,
            Active: true,
            AmountPaid: 0,
            UserModel: null,
            RaffleScheduleModel: null,
            RaffleTicketNumberModel: numbers
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'RaffleSellsPage?handler=CreateRaffleTicket',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('XSRF-TOKEN',
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend)
        }).then(function () {
            // ...
        });
    }
```

handler:

```
public JsonResult OnPostCreateRaffleTicket([FromBody]RaffleTicketModel dataToSend)
        {
            var result = dataToSend;
            return new JsonResult(result);
        }
```

Models:

```
public class RaffleTicketModel
    {
      
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int RaffleTicketId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RaffleSchedule")]
        public int RaffleScheduleId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserModel")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DatePaid { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Status { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public double AmountPaid { get; set; }

        public UserModel UserModel { get; set; }

        public RaffleScheduleModel RaffleScheduleModel { get; set; }

        public ICollection<RaffleTicketNumberModel> RaffleTicketNumberModel { get; set; }

    }
    public class RaffleTicketNumberModel {
        public int RaffleNumber { get; set; }

        public int AmountPaid { get; set; }
    }
    public class UserModel { }
    public class RaffleScheduleModel { }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked! Something I noticed is that the `then()` promise fails, because the browser refreshes inmediately after it hits the hanlder in the razor page, but if I change the `data` property of the ajax to `body`, the promise waits for the response and then reload the page but the parameter fails and comes as null again.

Comment: My code is exactly the same you provided in your answer, I just added `.then(function (data) {  console.log(data);  });` to the ajax just to test the response and promise but it fails as I mentioned in the past comment.

Comment: I can get the data,Can you create a new question,and completely show your code?I think there might be something wrong.